# Checking if someone has a role with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with discord.js but I have run into this error.
I know there are other articles about this, but I just can't get this to work.
I need to check if the user has an admin/mod role before running the command.

```
        case 'clear':
        if(!author.roles.cache.has('686001018277855308'))  return msg.reply('you dont have the permissions to do this.');
        else if(author.roles.cache.has('686001018277855308')){

            if(!args[1]) return msg.reply('please add the number of messages to clear in the command');
            else{
                msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
                msg.reply(args[1] + ' messages cleared!');
            }
        }

    break;
```

I just can't get this to work. I got the following error:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe index.js froggo is online!
>   c:\Users\frenc\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\froggobot\index.js:53
>               if(!author.roles.cache.has('686001018277855308'))  return msg.reply('you dont have the permissions to do this.');
>                                ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

If you need any other info, please ask in the comments.

One more question, is it possible to save this process as a single command and use it in other files without retyping the whole thing?

Comment: In your case `author.roles` is undefined. Answer to the last question: yes, this process need to save and use in other.

Comment: If `if(author.roles && ......`

Comment: i cant see the whole comment :( could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you just try to check if the user can delete messages sent by other people via a permissions check.

Here is what I would do :

```
case 'clear':
    if(!msg.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('you dont have the permissions to do this.');
    if(!args[1]) return msg.reply('please add the number of messages to clear in the command');

    msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
    msg.reply(args[1] + ' messages cleared!');
break;
```

Comment: tysm! it worked! i ended up making it check for the permission in the main bulkdelete command, and if that doesnt work it says that he doesnt have the perms. thanks again :)